# How can I modify the start time format in a PowerShell transcript log?

Tags: powershell

How can I change the format of the start time entry in the beginning of a PowerShell transcript log that has been created with the `Start-Transcript` cmdlet?

For example:

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20170424150539
Username: *******
RunAs User: ******
***********************
```

I would like this Start time to be in the following format: 2017-04-24 15:05:39

Comment: i need some option in start transcription command to change the time format automatically.
because the log file is generated automatically with the command start transcription
start-transcript -path $INSTALL_LOG -Append

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see there's no option on the `Start-Transcript` cmdlet to change the date format directly. However here's a way to do it after the transcript has been written with PowerShell:

```
$TranscriptFile = '.\PowerShell_transcript*.txt'   #Modify for your file.

$Transcript = Get-Content $TranscriptFile

$StartTime = ($Transcript -match "Start time: " -replace "Start time: ","")

If ($StartTime) {
    $NewStartTime = ([datetime]::ParseExact($StartTime, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat))
    $NewStartTime = Get-Date($NewStartTime) -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    $Transcript -replace $StartTime,$NewStartTime | Out-File $TranscriptFile
}
```

**Explanation:**

- Gets the start time string by matching 'Start Time: ' in the file and then removing that part of the string from the line.
- Uses `[datetime]::ParseExact` to replace the string with a valid datetime object by using datetime tokens: yyyyMMddhhmmss and based on your local culture setting for date.
- Converts the new date string to a datetime object with `get-date` and formats per your specified preference of "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
- Replaces the string in the transcript and writes it back to the file.

You could do the same for End time if you wanted to.

Comment: using this code i have this erreur  Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At C:\****************************************
+     $NewStartTime = ([datetime]::ParseExact($StartTime, "yyyyMMddhhmm ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException

Comment: It looks like it's complaining that $StartTime doesn't contain a string it recognises as a valid date. What country are you in? This will probably be to do with localisation issues (different date formats for different regions). I'd also check what is in $StartTime by doing a `Write-Host "$StartTime"` after it is created.

Comment: Write-Host "$StartTime" ====> 20170426160338

Comment: `"yyyyMMddhhmmss"` needs to be `"yyyyMMddHHmmss"`. The lowercase h was only working on 12 hour clock, so it was working in the morning (when I originally wrote it) but not for times that were after 12! :D

Comment: I've amended my answer accordingly. You want to do the same for the output format too I expect otherwise the time will be a little ambiguous.